# PHP Recursive Function to get n generations of x parents

Tags: php, recursion, breadth-first-search

I need to return family data (parents, siblings and partners) for 'x' number of generations (passed as $generations parameter) starting from a single person (passed as $id parameter). I can't assume two parents, this particular genealogy model has to allow for a dynamic number of parents (to allow for biological and adoptive relationships). I think my recursion is backwards, but I can't figure out how.

The code below is triggering my base clause 5 times, once for each generation, because $generation is being reduced by 1 not for every SET of parents but for every parent. What I want is for the base clause ($generations == 0) to only be triggered once, when 'x' number of generations for all parents of the initial person are fetched.

```js
public function fetchRelationships($id = 1, $generations = 5, $relationships = array())
{
  $perId = $id;
  if ($generations == 0) {
            return $relationships;
        } else {
            $parents = $this->fetchParents($perId);
            $relationships[$perId]['parents'] = $parents;
            $relationships[$perId]['partners'] = $this->fetchPartners($perId);
            if (!empty($parents)) {
                --$generations;
                foreach ($parents as $parentRel) {
                    $parent = $parentRel->getPer2();
                    $pid = $parent->getId();
                    $relationships[$perId]['siblings'][$pid] = $this->fetchSiblings($perId, $pid);
                    $perId = $pid;
                    $relationships[$perId] = $this->fetchRelationships($perId, $generations, $relationships);
                }
            }

            return $relationships;
        }
}
```

The methods fetchPartners, fetchParents and fetchSiblings just fetch the matching entities. So I am not pasting them here. Assuming that there are 2 parents, 5 generations and each generation has 2 parents then the return array should contain 62 elements, and should only trigger the base clause once those 62 elements are filled.

Thanks, in advance, for any help.

-----------Edit--------

Have rewritten with fetchSiblings and fetchPartners code removed to make it easier to read:

```js
public function fetchRelationships($id = 1, $generations = 5, $relationships = array())
{
  $perId = $id;
  if ($generations == 0) {
            return $relationships;
        } else {
            $parents = $this->fetchParents($perId);
            $relationships[$perId]['parents'] = $parents;
            if (!empty($parents)) {
                --$generations;
                foreach ($parents as $parentRel) {
                    $perId = $parentRel->getPer2()->getId();
                    $relationships[$perId] = $this->fetchRelationships($perId, $generations, $relationships);
                }
            }

            return $relationships;
        }
}
```

Comment: The five times may be a coincidence, not based on number of generations. It will have to call "base" clause more than once, because it is not a base, it is a tail.  Family branches out as you go up the tree. when generations = 0 you are at great, great, great grandparents. And you have more than 1!

Comment: Yeah, but I can't see how to fix it. I definitely don't want it hitting the base clause under any condition other than 'the whole tree is done'. I've been looking at breadth first but I'm not sure if it would work here.

Comment: it has to hit it multiple times. It doesn't matter. You've got bigger problems because you only ever create one array, and then that array has entries that reference the main array.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I understand that I have written the code in a way that means it will hit the clause more than once, that is the problem that I need help with. The array is passed so that it can be filled with data from subsequent generations, it is not my primary problem. I'm not convinced it is a problem. If my recursion is backwards, which I think it is, then my hope is that someone will be able to help me implement this.

Comment: When you iterate over the parent relations you modify `$perId` ... that seems odd, because it would seem that in the next iteration you would be querying the sibling of your parent being its own parent =S

Comment: In the next iteration I am getting siblings of the parent with fetchSiblings. I need to get siblings, parents and partners for each person in the tree. But, I am not doing anything with the siblings - just filling the 'siblings' element of that person's array in the containing 'relationships' array. I modify $perId to the parent right before the recursion. So I should always be working with a parent, grandparent, great grandparent...

Answer (score 0):

Garr Godfrey got it right.  $generations will equal zero when it reaches the end of each branch.  So you'll hit the "base clause" as many times as there are branches.  in the `foreach ($parents as $parentRel)` loop, you call `fetchRelationships` for each parent.  That's two branches, so you'll have two calls to the "base clause".  Then for each of their parents, you'll have another two calls to the "base clause", and so on...

Also, you're passing back and forth the `relationships`, making elements of it refer back to itself.  I realize you're just trying to retain information as you go, but you're actually creating lots of needless self-references.

Try this

```
public function fetchRelationships($id = 1, $generations = 5)
{
  $perId = $id;
  $relationships = array();
  if ($generations == 0) {
            return $relationships;
        } else {
            $parents = $this->fetchParents($perId);
            $relationships[$perId]['parents'] = $parents;
            if (!empty($parents)) {
                --$generations;
                foreach ($parents as $parentRel) {
                    $perId = $parentRel->getPer2()->getId();
                    $relationships[$perId] = $this->fetchRelationships($perId, $generations);
                }
            }

            return $relationships;
        }
}
```

you'll still hit the base clause multiple times, but that shouldn't matter.

you might be thinking "but then i will lose some of the data in `$relationships`", but you won't.  It's all there from the recursive returns.

Answer (score 0):

If you're pulling this out of a database, [have you considered having the query do all of the leg work for you?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30021/mysql-tree-hierarchical-query)

Not sure how you need the data stacked or excluded, but here's one way to do it:

```
<?php   

class TreeMember {
    public $id;
    // All three should return something like:
    // array( $id1 => $obj1, $id2 => $obj2 )
    // and would be based on $this->$id
    public function fetchParents(){ return array(); }
    public function fetchPartners(){ return array(); };
    public function fetchSiblings(){ return array(); }; 

    public function fetchRelationships($generations = 5)
    {
        // If no more to go
        if ($generations == 0) { return; }   

        $branch = array();
        $branch['parents'] = $this->fetchParents();
        $branch['partners'] = $this->fetchPartners();
        $branch['partners'] = $this->fetchSiblings();   

        // Logic
        $generations--;
        foreach($branch as $tmType, $tmArr)
        {
            foreach($tmArr as $tmId => $tmObj)
            {
                $branch[$tmType][$tmId] =
                    $mObj->fetchRelationships
                    (
                        $generations
                    )
                );
        }); 

        return array($this->id => $branch);
    }
}
```